# strlen an array has different result

Tags: c, arrays, linux, char, strlen

```
unsigned char kk[16] = {129, 254, 139, 254, 135, 87, 108, 62, 203, 34, 66, 111, 142, 87, 132, 115};
unsigned char kkf[20] = {24, 165, 227, 127, 183, 90, 60, 22, 128, 165, 7, 52, 151, 238, 69, 203, 42, 213, 220, 57};
printf("strlen kk: %d\n", strlen(kk)); //should be 16
printf("strlen kkf: %d\n", strlen(kkf) //should be 20
```

The output is

```
strlen kk: 16
strlen kkf: 22 //insane????????
```

Why the length of kkf[20] is 22? Is it obvious 20? I compiled it on Linux. What happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have abused `strlen` and invoked undefined behavior.  It is for measuring the length of *strings* (NUL terminated character sequences), not arbitrary arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings are zero-terminated, meaning that you need to have a zero character at the end of each of your arrays. Change the code to:

```
unsigned char kk[17]  = {129, 254, 139, 254, 135, 87, 108,  62,
                         203,  34,  66, 111, 142, 87, 132, 115, 0};
unsigned char kkf[21] = { 24, 165, 227, 127, 183, 90,  60,  22,
                         128, 165,   7,  52, 151, 238, 69, 203,
                          42, 213, 220,  57,   0};
printf("strlen kk: %d\n", strlen(kk)); //should be 16
printf("strlen kkf: %d\n", strlen(kkf) //should be 20
```

In the case of your original code you got lucky with the first array, and it just happened to have a zero character after the last element created by the literal.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Maybe `unsigned char kk[]` instead?

Comment: @chux: the zero character is still needed as a terminator if the intent is to treat the array as a string.

Comment: More clearly: Suggest `unsigned char kk[]` instead of `unsigned char kk[17]`.  In either case, the array should terminate with a null character to make it a string.

Answer (score 3):

strlen() counts characters until it finds '\0', which you have not provided. It just so happens that there's a '\0' value 16 bytes from the end of kk, and one 22 bytes from the end of kkf, but that's purely by chance.